Combine Legends with Lines and Points
I can't seem to figure out how to combine these legends. Can anyone help?
Here's a MWE
data("iris")
iris <- iris %>% mutate(smell = if_else(Species %in% "setosa","smells good", "does not smell good"))

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species ,shape = smell)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species, shape =smell)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Species))+
  labs(color = "species",shape = "species")

Which gives this
(https://i.sstatic.net/MpbNz.png)
I want a single legend showing both color and shape. I know it's possible but can't seem to make it happen.

I want the shape and color combined into a single legend titled "species". I will put in a caption what the shape refers to so I don't want that explicit in the legend. Do I need to use scale_color_manual() and scale_shape_manual() even thought I am not invoking those already?

The legend icon for setosa should have a red triangle. The legend icon for versicolor should be a green circle. The legend entry for virginica should be a blue circle. This is as they appear in the graph.

smells good is indicated by marker shape in the legend.
